# How to redirect after successful login in PHP?

Tags: php, authentication, header, refresh

I'm trying to make work this code, but for some reason I can't:

```
<?php
include 'AS.php';

//csrf protection
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') 
    die("Sorry bro!");

$url = parse_url( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '');
if( !isset( $url['host']) || ($url['host'] != $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
    die("Sorry bro!");

$action = $_POST['action'];

switch ($action) {
    case 'checkLogin':
        $logged = $login->userLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
        if($logged === true)
header( "refresh: 5; url=index.php" ); 
echo 'You\'ll be redirected in about 5 secs. ';
echo 'If not, click <a href="index.php">here</a>.';
        break;
```

For some reason header( "refresh: 5; url=index.php" ); is not working, since have no effect on the page.

if i try just header to redirect, it does the job, but page don´t load corectly, it loads with some CSS issues, so i decide to use refresh.

The idea is that when user is loged in, it just refresh the page, so he will be in the backend area of my script.

Ok, so i think is my mistake dont explain well the situation:

I have this script, the original code is this:

```
<?php
include 'AS.php';

//csrf protection
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') 
    die("Sorry bro!");

$url = parse_url( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '');
if( !isset( $url['host']) || ($url['host'] != $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
    die("Sorry bro!");

$action = $_POST['action'];

switch ($action) {
    case 'checkLogin':
        $logged = $login->userLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
        if($logged === true)
            echo "true";
        break;

    case "registerUser":
        $register->register($_POST['user']);
        break;

    case "addUser":
        $registeruser->registeruser($_POST['user']);
        break;

    case "resetPassword":
        $register->resetPassword($_POST['newPass'], $_POST['key']);
        break;

    case "forgotPassword":
        $register->forgotPassword($_POST['email']);
        break;

    case "logout":
        ASSession::destroySession();
        break;

    case "postComment":
        $ASComment = new ASComment();
        echo $ASComment->insertComment(ASSession::get("user_id"), $_POST['comment']);
        break;

    case "updatePassword":
        $user = new ASUser(ASSession::get("user_id"));
        $user->updatePassword($_POST['oldpass'], $_POST['newpass']);
        break;

    case "updateDetails":
        $user = new ASUser(ASSession::get("user_id"));
        $user->updateDetails($_POST['details']);
        break;

    case "updateEmail":
        $user = new ASUser(ASSession::get("user_id"));
        $user->updateEmail($_POST['email']);
        break;

    case "updateUser":
        $loggedUser = new ASUser(ASSession::get("user_id"));
        if(!$loggedUser->isAdmin()) exit();
        //$idusuario = ASSession::get("iduser");
        $username = $_POST['userdata']['username'];
        $result = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `as_users` WHERE `username` = :u", array( 'u' => $username ));
        $user = new ASUser($result[0]['user_id']);
        $user->updateUser($_POST['userdata']);
        break;

    case "updatePass":
        $loggedUser = new ASUser(ASSession::get("user_id"));
        if(!$loggedUser->isAdmin()) exit();
        $idusuario = ASSession::get("iduser");
        $result = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `as_users` WHERE `user_id` = :u", array( 'u' => $idusuario ));
        $user = new ASUser($result[0]['user_id']);
        $user->updatePass($_POST['newpass']);
        break;

    case "changeRole":
        $loggedUser = new ASUser(ASSession::get("user_id"));
        if(!$loggedUser->isAdmin()) exit();

        $user = new ASUser($_POST['userId']);
        echo ucfirst($user->changeRole());
        break;

    case "deleteUser":
        $loggedUser = new ASUser(ASSession::get("user_id"));
        if(!$loggedUser->isAdmin()) exit();

        $user = new ASUser($_POST['userId']);
        $user->deleteUser();
        break;

    case "getUserDetails":
        $user = new ASUser($_POST['userId']);
        $loggedUser = new ASUser(ASSession::get("user_id"));
        if(!$loggedUser->isAdmin()) exit();

        $info = $user->getInfo();

        //prepare and output result
        $result             = $user->getDetails();
        $result['email']    = $info['email'];
        $result['username'] = $info['username'];
        echo json_encode($result);
        break;

    case "addRole": 
        $loggedUser = new ASUser(ASSession::get("user_id"));
        if(!$loggedUser->isAdmin()) exit();

        $res = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `as_user_roles` WHERE `role` = :r", array( 'r' => $_POST['role'] ));
        if(count($res) == 0) {
            $db->insert("as_user_roles", array("role" => strtolower(strip_tags($_POST['role']))));
            $result = array(
                "status"   => "success",
                "roleName" => strip_tags($_POST['role']),
                "roleId"   => $db->lastInsertId()
            );
        }
        else {
            $result = array(
                "status" => "error",
                "message" => "Role already exists."
            );
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
        break;

    case "deleteRole":
        $loggedUser = new ASUser(ASSession::get("user_id"));
        if(!$loggedUser->isAdmin()) exit(); 

        //default user roles can't be deleted
        if(in_array($_POST['roleId'], array(1,2,3)) )
            exit();

        $db->delete("as_user_roles", "role_id = :id", array(
            "id" => $_POST['roleId']
        ));
        $db->update("as_users", array( 'user_role' => "1" ), "user_role = :r", array( "r" => $_POST['roleId'] ) );
        break;


    default:

        break;
}
```

The problem is, the script is made in order to work with ajax, and it should, reload the page with ajax, but is not, I'm running this script on a subdomain, also i have a wordpress installation in the main domain, and Ajax works well, but I'm not sure why is not working on this script, so i decide that maybe reloading the page after login form is submitted the issue would be solved.

The thing is, when i submit the form, it only display: "true" message, but it doesn´t reload the page, if i manually reload the page, so it works, and im already loged in. this is the whole problem.

Im still a noob in the whole coding stuffs, but I'm trying hard, if there is any other code you need, in order to make this more clear, I'll try to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all help, at the end i find out this code, and it worked great, also the login validation is working propertly, this is the code changed and working:

```
`<?php
include 'AS.php';

//csrf protection
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') 
    die("Sorry bro!");

$url = parse_url( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '');
if( !isset( $url['host']) || ($url['host'] != $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
    die("Sorry bro!");

$action = $_POST['action'];

switch ($action) {
    case 'checkLogin':
        $logged = $login->userLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
        if($logged === true)
echo '<script>parent.window.location.reload(true);</script>';
        break;`
```

This did the trick:

`echo '<script>parent.window.location.reload(true);</script>';`

Im wondering if is possible to add a delay to this reload, so i can put a message before login, and alos im wondering if this way is safe to do this.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the Location header, ie:

```
header('Location: /home.php');
```

instead of:

```
header( "refresh: 5; url=index.php" );
```

Comment: Yes i tried that, but when redirect it everything is messed up, page dont load correctly

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the way you are linking to your css/etc files or the way your 'home.php' (example) is being loaded. If you post the content of that file it might help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that $logged giving back true?

```
if($logged === true)
header( "refresh: 5; url=index.php" ); 
echo 'You\'ll be redirected in about 5 secs. ';
echo 'If not, click <a href="index.php">here</a>.';
```

cause if it doesn't it'll still write out echo text but header won't run.

make sure using this code (using {} brackets)

```
if($logged === true)
{
    header( "refresh: 5; url=index.php" ); 
    echo 'You\'ll be redirected in about 5 secs. ';
    echo 'If not, click <a href="index.php">here</a>.';
}
else
{
    echo 'Wrong username or password!';
}
```

Comment: Im going to try that, let me check, and thanks for helping :)

Comment: I update the description of my problem, and your code doesn´t work, but can you check the description again, i explained better what is happening. Thanks :)

Comment: Are you still using ajax for log in or you updated your form to send form data directly to the file? (<form method='post' action='file_name_which_contains_the_code'>...</form>)